# ALT key and left mouse button combination when dragging item from ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Here's the code for my ListBox MouseMove event:

```
private void lbxItems_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) //this one is good
    {
        lbxItems.DoDragDrop("Copy Text 1", DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
    else if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) //this desn't work
    {
        lbxItems.DoDragDrop("Copy Text 2", DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

The `e.Button == MouseButtons.Left` condition alone works okay, but not with `Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt`. I wonder if the ListBox control can recognize ALT key + Left Mousebutton combination. Can anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, well, I think I found a fix here, which is pretty easy.

To make it work, I just need to evaluate the `Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt` condition first and put `e.Button == MouseButtons.Left` in the `else if` statement. Thus, ALT + Left Mousebutton will always be checked first.

```
private void lbxItems_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    {
        lbxItems.DoDragDrop("Copy Text 1", DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    {
        lbxItems.DoDragDrop("Copy Text 2", DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

Also, I have to point out that it's not `Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt` didn't work, just the original code never got chance to run `else if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you did it. You need to capture Alt key being pressed first by using relevant key press handler and store it in some shared variable, then when mouse gets moved you can check whether alt key was pressed by accessing shared variable.